# Converting result from handler in array format

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

as a new bee in Development, i have a question how can i get data according to my requeriment of what is the best practic

My design is like this.

Java script (Ajax call)  >> ashx handler (Hit databse and return data) >> databse (my values)

i need data like this in order to render in HTML

```
 var events_array = new Array();
            events_array[0] = {
                startDate: new Date(2013, 01, 25),
                endDate: new Date(2013, 01, 25),
                title: "Event 2013, 01, 25",
                description: "Description 2013, 01, 25",
                priority: 1, // 1 = Low, 2 = Medium, 3 = Urgent
                frecuency: 1 // 1 = Daily, 2 = Weekly, 3 = Monthly, 4 = Yearly
            };

            events_array[1] = {
                startDate: new Date(2013, 01, 24),
                endDate: new Date(2013, 01, 24),
                title: "Event 2013, 01, 24",
                description: "Description 2013, 01, 24",
                priority: 2, // 1 = Low, 2 = Medium, 3 = Urgent
                frecuency: 1 // 1 = Daily, 2 = Weekly, 3 = Monthly, 4 = Yearly
            }

            events_array[2] = {
                startDate: new Date(2013, 01, 07),
                endDate: new Date(2013, 01, 07),
                title: "Event 2013, 01, 07",
                description: "2013, 01, 07",
                priority: 3, // 1 = Low, 2 = Medium, 3 = Urgent
                frecuency: 1 // 1 = Daily, 2 = Weekly, 3 = Monthly, 4 = Yearly
            }
```

i want to know how can i send data like this from my ashx handler.

I have a class to EventEnfo. Can i pass list of EventInfo from handler and format/convert this in array like above? ? Any example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). So you could start by designing a model that will match the desired JSON structure:

```
public class EventInfo
{
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then inside your handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{ 
    IEnumerable<EventInfo> result = ... fetch from db
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result));
}
```

---

UPDATE:

And here's how you could consume the results:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myhandler.ashx',
    success: function(events) {
        $.each(events, function() {
            alert('Title of the event: ' + this.title);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes i did that and successded. just wana know how can i iterate on that data return my handler to construct array like that?

Comment: i can see values by doing this result[0].title

Comment: You could use the `$.each` method to loop through the results returned by the handler. I have updated my answer to shown an example.

Answer (score 2):

events_array is not an array its an object, so doing new Array is wrong. do new Object or better {}:

```
var events_array = {};
events_array[0] = {...
```

if your backend can convert stuff into an JSON object you can send it via ajax to the client-side and parse it

```
JSON.parse(obj);
```

Comment: m using this JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string serEmployee = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(employee);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";\
        context.Response.Write(serEmployee);
from backend when returning response to ajax call. Dont know you to fill that array then

Comment: context.Response.ContentType must be "application/json" then!